# SVN Workingcopy over NFS

Tags: linux, svn, nfs

Is there a way to boost svn performance when the working copy is running over NFS?

(*) It is required for it to be and the NFS mounted partition (/home).

I guess SVN client reads the whole tree looking for changes when commiting. I don't have an idea of what can make a checkout slow.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Subversion FAQ](https://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#nfs):

> Working copies can be stored on NFS (one common scenario is when your home directory is on a NFS server). On Linux NFS servers, due to the volume of renames used internally in Subversion when checking out files, some users have reported that 'subtree checking' should be disabled (it's enabled by default). Please see [NFS Howto Server Guide](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/nfs-howto/ar01s03.html) and exports(5) for more information on how to disable subtree checking.

Checkout performance can be constrained by a few factors, but most likely in your case it's I/O to that NFS mount - unless you're saturating the network connection, or the server is undersized.

Comment: The poor performance is not only visible at checkout - it also effects merges and commits (and this is even more problematic because you do these actions far more often than checking out). I'd expected that subversion 1.7 which uses a database instead of the .svn directories in every directory would speed up svn actions massively on a NFS share. However, the opposite is true: for most actions there's a slight performance degradation.

Answer (score 0):

Use "nolock" option to mount. It is actually OS local lock, not NFS server side lock.

I got better performance from this option.

Answer (score -1):

Checkout performance over NFS is abysmal, to the point that it becomes the major bottleneck, not the bandwidth to the Subversion server. [rsvn](http://www.veripool.org/projects/rsvn/wiki/Intro) by Bryce Denney and Wilson Snyder is a perl script that logs into the NFS server using ssh (assuming that is allowed) and runs the svn command remotely. In my tests it gives orders of magnitude faster performance. Excerpt from the man page:

> NAME
>
> rsvn - remote svn - run subversion commands on the file server if possible
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> rsvn ANY_SVN_COMMAND
>     rsvn update
>     rsvn --test
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> When possible, run the svn command on the file server where it does not have to wait for NFS. Otherwise run svn as usual. Some SVN commands will always run locally, either for "safety" or because there is no benefit of running on the file server (svn log).
>
> The commands that will be sent to the file server by default are these (and their abbreviations):
>
> ```
> add checkout cleanup diff merge resolved
> revert status switch update
> ```
>
> Why is commit not run remotely? Because it will either start an editor, which won't always work through noninteractive SSH, or you might use -m "FOO BAR" and the shell's quoting gets all screwed up. It would be good to figure out how to solve these problems, and add "commit" to the list.